# Check if a point is inside a GeoJSON polygon in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, point-in-polygon, leaflet-plugins

I am trying to determine if a point is inside a GeoJSON polygon or not, using the [Leaflet.PointInPolygon](https://github.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon) plugin. See example code below:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon/v1.0.0/wise-leaflet-pip.js"></script>
<script src="municipalities.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

var layer = L.geoJson(municipalities, {
    style: function (feature) {
        return {
            color: "#000",
            weight: 2,
            fillOpacity: 0
        };
    },
    filter: function (feature, layer) {                     
        if (feature.properties.CAT_B === "ETH") return true
    },
}).addTo(map);

var point = L.marker([-29, 25]).addTo(map);

console.log(layer.contains(point.getLatLng()));
```

However, I get the error **layer.contains is not a function**. The output should be true or false.

If I replace the GeoJSON with a simple polygon it works, such as:

```
var polygon = L.polygon([
  [51.51, -0.08],
  [51.503, -0.06],
  [51.51, -0.047]
]).addTo(map);
```

I think I might need to convert the GeoJSON to a L.polygon somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the docs of [Leaflet.PointInPolygon](https://github.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon) plugin, you'll se that it works only for the following type of layers: `L.polygon`, `L.polyline`, and `L.latLng`.

`L.geoJSON` is a group layer that contains those kinds of layers, so you have to iterate through it's layers with `.eachLayer` method to use plugin `.contains` method.

Code could then look something like this:

```
layer.eachLayer(function(memberLayer) {
  if (memberLayer.contains(point.getLatLng())) {
    console.log(memberLayer.feature.properties);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The contains() function only checks the bounds. The bounds are always imprecise outlines. For an accurate and quick solution, I suggest:

A combination of contains() and the raytracing algorithm, adapted to L.geoJSON type: multipolygon.

First it is quickly checked with contains() and then each polygon is searched exactly.

```
                Object.keys( listMarker ).forEach( function(key){

                marker_Object = listMarker[key];
                //region type of -> L.geoJson
                if (region.getBounds().contains(marker_Object.getLatLng())) {
                    region.eachLayer(function(memberLayer) {

                        if (memberLayer.getBounds().contains(marker_Object.getLatLng())) {

                            if(isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker_Object, memberLayer)){
                                console.log('Marker is located in region');
                          
                                marker_Object.addTo(map);

                                
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }

                function isMarkerInsidePolygon(marker, poly) {
                    var x = marker.getLatLng().lat, y = marker.getLatLng().lng;
        
                        var polyPoints = poly.getLatLngs()[0][0];
            
                        var inside = false;
                     
                        for (var i = 0, j = polyPoints.length - 1; i < polyPoints.length; j = i++) {
     
                            var xi = polyPoints[i].lat, yi = polyPoints[i].lng;
                            var xj = polyPoints[j].lat, yj = polyPoints[j].lng;

                            var intersect = ((yi > y) !== (yj > y))
                                && (x < ((xj - xi) * (y - yi) / (yj - yi) + xi));
                            if (intersect) {
                                inside = !inside;
                           
                            }
                        }

                    
                    return inside;
                }


            });
```