# Using marker drag event instead mouseover on each polygan layer in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, layers, markers, events

I want to use this leaflet example:

https://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/example.html

with some changes:

1. add a marker to map. i done it like this:

   ```
   var center=[ 37.8, -96 ];
        marker = new L.Marker(center, {
            draggable: true,
            autoPan:true,
        }).addTo(map);
   ```
2. problem:

In above example , when the mouse moves over a layer, then the **highlightFeature** function is executed with **mouseover event** and the layer is highlighted.

Now, I want to use the *marker drag event* instead of the *mouseover* event.
run **highlightFeature** when a **marker is dragging** over a layer.

```
       layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: zoomToFeature     });
```

can i use marker events on each layer?

I will be happy for your help.

Comment: What have you tried? There is no marker in the above code or in the mentioned example. Have a look at marker [docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker), Dragging event sections. Please edit your question and add more relevant code regarding marker.

Comment: i edited my question.if my qoustion has problem say me again.thank you.

Comment: in above example : can i use markerdragging event  instead mouseover event after add a marker to map? 
markerdrag event
instead :
mouseover: highlightFeature

Comment: Before you edited the question, there was one additional requirement: (3) marker dragend event instead click : when dragging marker was end and user release the marker , then run zoomToFeature for zoom to marker and layer. Is this no more required?

Comment: i use your answer in another question. then define marker dragend event for zoomToFeature , marker drag event for highlightFeature. in marker drag event check position of marker like your answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438504/233405

Comment: excuse me my friend if my question was bad...thank you.your answer was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution where you have to iterate over all GeoJSON polygons at each marker `drag` event can be quite costly when there is a big number of polygons.

One possible solution to avoid this is using the following method:

- Create marker with `interactive: false` option so it won't catch mouse events.
- Create marker icon with some dummy CSS class `className: 'my-marker'` which will be use to identify marker HTML element.
- Create map `mousedown` event processing function, where event is checked if it falls on marker by temporarily making marker interactive and using `document.elementFromPoint` method to get element under cursor.
- If event falls on marker, disable map dragging and move marker while dragging mouse with processing map `mousemove` event.
- On first `mouseup` event make map draggable again and stop listening to `mousemove` event.

Code could then look something like this (tested):

```
const marker = L.marker([29, -106], {
  interactive: false,
  icon: new L.Icon.Default({
    className: 'my-marker'
  })
}).addTo(map);

map.on('mousedown', function(e) {
  const markerElement = marker.getElement();
  markerElement.classList.add('leaflet-interactive');
  const target = document.elementFromPoint(e.originalEvent.clientX, e.originalEvent.clientY);
  markerElement.classList.remove('leaflet-interactive');
  if (target.classList.contains('my-marker')) {
    map.dragging.disable();
    map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
      marker.setLatLng(e.latlng);
    });
    map.once('mouseup',function(e){
     map.removeEventListener('mousemove');
     map.dragging.enable();
    })          
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your completed answer

Answer (score 0):

i solved it .
i define marker drag event and get current latlng of marker.
then i check in my geojson file for each polygan layer .
i check if the new marker position falls within the layer.

thank you from

[**Tomazicm**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104146/tomazicm)

[your answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/438504/233405) in another question helped me.